# jQuery: Get last row column selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have the following row in a table:

```
<tr><td>Adric cut-out</td><td><span class="quantity">0</span></td><td>worthless</td></tr>
```

I've already got the span with the class 'quantity' selected, but I'm having no luck getting the last TD element in the row selected. I can do it by getting its parent, then its parent, then the last TD child element but is there something a little more efficient?

Using this as a start, how would I select the TD element containing the price?
Note, it will always be the last item on the row.

Comment: No there isn't, even if there's, the difference won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is consistent, stepping up and over to the next column should be fairly efficient:

```
var price = $('.quantity').closest('td').next().html();
```

It might be faster to simply assign a class (`price`?) to the last `td` and collect that, though.

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://jsbin.com/odacar

Which alerts the last TD using this:

```
function doAlert() {
  alert($('td:last').html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the last selector - http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

$('tr').children('td:last')